# Sind erwidern und antworten austauschbar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb

> "Wo gehst du hin? " fragt Klaus
>
> "Ich gehe in den Park." **erwidert** Jana

Meine Frage ist : Kann man `erwidern` anstatt von `antworten` im Zusammenhang verwenden?

Comment: Schreibst Du „im Zusammenhang“ frage ich mich, in welchem. Du meinst wohl „in dem“ oder besser „in diesem“.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meistens.

Eine Erwiderung hat manchmal den Beigeschmack von "widersprechen", eine Antwort nicht.

Comment: Wobei ein(e) Antwort ursprünglich eine Erwiderung war.

Answer (score 1):

Im konkreten Zusammenhang, den die Frage betrifft, sind diese Verben austauschbar. Es gibt jedoch Situationen, in denen nur „erwidern“ gebraucht werden kann. Etwa solche:

> Sie erwidert diese Gefühle nicht und spottet seiner bei jeder Gelegenheit.

Ich würde sagen, dass beim Gebrauch im übertragenen Sinne „erwidern“ öfter genutzt werden kann. Ich glaube aber, dass es langsam ausstirbt. Statt:

> Das Land erwiderte den Luftangriff mit einer Kriegserklärung,

wird man heute wohl Folgendes hören:

> Das Land antwortete mit einer Kriegserklärung auf den Luftangriff.

Comment: Danke für das edit:)

Answer (score 0):

"erwidern" ist eine Variante für "antworten". Nicht so häufig wie antworten und wohl etwas gehobener.

Comment: Achso. Dieses Verb sieht man immer in älteren Taschenbüchern.

Comment: Nein, *erwidern* kann auch *entgegnen* bedeuten.

Comment: In Romanen sind "sagen, antworten, erwidern, entgegnen, meinen etc" reine  inquit-Formeln, also Verben nach direkter Rede und ein Autor variert natürlich und schreibt nicht tausendmal "sagte er". Als inquit-Formeln sind diese Verben reine Varianten und beliebig austauschbar. ( inquit, lateinisch er/sie/es sagt/sagte)